# Road Bike Wheel Replacement

Tags: road-bike, wheels

Simple question for a new cyclist. I want to change my wheelset to these (http://www.rolwheels.com/wheels/wheel/volant-r-t).

Will they be compliant with my current bike? (https://www.norco.com/bike-archives/2015/valence-a3/).

Thanks,

edit: Also, what parameters and specs can I use to determine this on my own?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Ryan. The answer is *yes*. A better question would get a more expansive answer, for example "what factors tell me whether particular wheels will fit my bike?"

Comment: Absolutely true. Could you expand on those factors?

Comment: @Ryan you're supposed to edit your question to ask this, then we can expand on those factors.

Comment: The second answer you might want to ask yourself (not SE) is "why"? Its a relatively expensive wheelset to put on a relatively cheap (and new) bike.

Comment: @Batman - been having numerous problems with the stock wheelset. After my fourth broken spoke in a month and change, I've accepted that perhaps my wheels are too far gone.

Comment: ROL would be able to give you an authorative answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer** *Looks* like a straight swap (but the proof is always in the doing.)

Neither link say what size the wheels are, so assuming the most common 700c size for both and the wheels will fit under the brake bridge.

Neither link says anything about spacing, but we can expect the front is 100mm over-locknut because that's standard, and the rear will also be 130mm (check this) which is the standard for 9-11 speed.

The cassette should swap over okay, yours is 9 speed and the new wheel is 9/10/11 speed.

Rim brakes will need some adjustment, but both rims are alloy so the brake pads shouldn't need to change type.  You may choose to replace brake pads anyway so there's a fresh surface to work with.

**Observations**:

The new wheels say "Recommended rider weight limit is 109kg (240lb)" so that should be noted.

You're going from a 28 spoke front to a 24 spoke front wheel.

---

Have you considered investigating why your current wheels are loosing spokes?  Could be a badly machine-assembled wheel, or budget spokes.  A bike that has been left out in the weather for years can suffer, but that's probably not the cause here.

Are your spokes all breaking on the rear or the front or a mixture ?

Freedom isn't exactly a high quality brand, so rebuilding the old wheel on new spokes may not be worth doing, unless you will try it yourself.

I see there's a 32 hole version of the wheel as well.  Could be your norco bike is rated for a lighter rider ?

Comment: I have a strong feeling that it has to do with my physical build. I'm not a small guy, at about 6'3 and 220lbs, I have a feeling that the current cheap wheels are not going to cut it, despite me rebuilding it.

Right now, it's been all rear wheel spoke breaks. The front wheel feels as true as can be, but the rear has never felt the same since the first break.

Comment: @ryan Fair call - If I were in your position I'd consider replacing the rear wheel only.   Also consider your riding technique... avoid kerbs/curbs and potholes and be careful to unweight the rear when going over train tracks or road joints.   If you're handy with tools, get a spoke tool and play with the wheel a bit.  Lightly tap each spoke with a metal tool and they should sound "close"  there shouldn't be one that's a higher *TINK* or lower *thonk* noise.   Also, carry less stuff on the bike if you can.